# How do I get xml tag attributes in converted array using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having below xml data. There is the questions in `<question>` and all possible answers are in `<answer>`. The `<answer>` tag have attribute "correct" which is the correct answer of that question.
So here I am trying to read this "Correct" attribute of `<answer>`.
Here when I used "simplexml_load_string" function it converts xml to php array but it does not return this "Correct" attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

`<questions>
<question type="1" text="Which one of the following addresses is associated with you?">
        <answer correct="false">ABC</answer>
        <answer correct="false">PQR</answer>
        <answer correct="false">ASD</answer>
        <answer correct="false">5374 </answer>
        <answer correct="false">8288 SELKIRK</answer>
        <answer correct="false">1558 NICHOLS</answer>
        <answer correct="true">1400 AMERICAN LN</answer>
        <answer correct="false">None of the above</answer>
      </Question>
</Questions>`

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml is case sensitive. If turn `</Question>` and `</Questions>` into lowercase, all works fine:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->xpath('/questions/question/answer') as $ans)
   echo $ans['correct'] .' : ' . $ans . "\n";
```

result:

```
false : ABC
false : PQR
false : ASD
false : 5374 
false : 8288 SELKIRK
false : 1558 NICHOLS
true : 1400 AMERICAN LN
false : None of the above
```

[demo](https://eval.in/584018)